# intellij idea generate persistence mapping have no foreign key

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, mapping, persistence

I use Intellij idea 15 `generate persistence mapping` to auto generate Entity code but there is no foreign key like `@ManyToOne()` or `@OneToMany`, so I think there must something wrong. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Intellij IDEA 16 If we are just checking the tables of which entity we have to make in the persistence tool window it doesn't include the foreign key relationships. So go in the drop down of all the tables and manually check all the relationship you wants to include and then try to generate the entities. It works for me.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Is there a way to select all automatically?